# How does frame forwarding work with bridge and virtual interfaces

Tags: linux, ethernet, bridge

I am trying to understand how linux bridges work and I am having trouble wrapping my head around how it works with virtual ethernet devices.

So bridges are kind of like hubs but they maintain Mac learning database so that unicast addresses can be forwarded to the right port once the mac address and port mapping is learned.

What I am not sure is how does this work with virtual ethernet devices where one end of the pair is inside the namespace and the other in bridge.
I can see that virtual ethernet devices have their own mac addresses but are these mac addresses public? Does the bridge act like a hub in that case and broadcasts every frame since all frames have the same public mac address.

Thanks